# Segmentation fault likely during creation of struct | c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have the following code in which I am iterating through the lines of a csv file and comparing the inputted name to the field in the csv file which contains the name, to see if the names are the same.

```
struct logrecord
{
        char name[100];
        char IPAddress[50];
};

bool checkNameExists(FILE* csvfile, char* name, char* ip)
{
// Read through the CSV data file, keep looking for the name.
// If found, store the IP address associated with the name to the variable ip and return success.
// Is bool a valid data type in C? How do you indicate true/false concept in C?

        //iterate through each line in file
        char line[200];
        while(fgets(line, 200, csvfile)){
                struct logrecord studentinfo;
                studentinfo = readLog(line);
                if ((strcmp(studentinfo.name, name))== 0){
                        printf("name found");
                        break;
                }
        }
}

struct logrecord readLog(char* logline)
{
// parse a character array that contains an line from the log
// and return a structure that contains the fileds of interest to us.
        struct logrecord studentinfo;

        printf("%s\n", logline);
        //break input line into an array of tokens
        const char s[2] = ",";
        char * token[200];
        token[0] = strtok(logline, s);
        strcpy( studentinfo.name, token[0] );

        printf("%s\n", studentinfo.name);

        int i;
        for ( i = 0; i < 200; i++ ){
                if ( (token[i] = strtok( NULL, " " )) == NULL ){
                        break;
                }
        }
        strcpy( studentinfo.IPAddress, token[5]);
        printf("%s\n", studentinfo.IPAddress);
        return studentinfo;

}

//main where checkNameExists is being called
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

        FILE *data;
        data = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (data == NULL){
                printf("error opening CSV file");
                return 1;
        }
        //get structure of student
        /*
        char str[200];
        char * logline = fgets(str, 200, data );
        readLog(logline);
        */

        //check if name exists
        char *ip;
        checkNameExists(data, argv[2], ip);
}
```

when I pass the following argument to the c file:

./ a.out data.csv Devon Estrada

I get the following:

User, Attempt, Date, Time, Event, IP Address

User \n
Address \n

Raveena Mullen,1,"Oct 9, 2020",4:54 AM,Quiz Entry,157.149.164.98

Raveena \n
Mullen \n
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

---

for reference my CSV file is structured like this:

```
User, Attempt, Date, Time, Event, IP Address
Raveena Mullen,1,"Oct 9, 2020",4:54 AM,Quiz Entry,157.149.164.98
Raveena Mullen,1,"Oct 9, 2020",4:54 AM,Response to Question Saved,157.149.164.98
Devon Estrada,1,"Oct 9, 2020",4:53 AM,Quiz Completion,141.176.32.7
Aleena Escobar,1,"Oct 9, 2020",5:56 AM,Quiz Entry,181.253.148.223
Aleena Escobar,1,"Oct 9, 2020",5:58 AM,Response to Question 2 Saved,181.253.148.223
```

Comment: How is `struct logrecord` defined?

Comment: After the first `strtok`, you use space to tokenize, not a comma. That means that the "Raveena" line after the first comma will have 5 tokens, but you try to access `token[5]`, which is `NULL`, the return value of `strtok` when you break out of the loop. You should check whether a token exists before accessing it.

Comment: struct logrecord has been updated @ForceBru